# How to set states with props in react.js ES6

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack

I would like to know, how to set my states with props parameters using ES6

**Before:**

```
const MyComponent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      name: this.props.name || 'Initial data...'
    };
  }
});
```

And now I'm trying to do this and `this.props` doesn't exist:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
      this.state = { name: this.props.name || 'Joseph Flowers' };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, you don't need a statefull component for what you're trying to do (anti-pattern : https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html).

Instead, another simpler, better solution :

```
class MyComponent extends React.PureComponent {

    static propTypes = {            // <- This is not related to your question
        name: PropTypes.string,     //    but always declare your propTypes :-)
    }

    static defaultProps = {         // <- React provides defaultProps specifically
        name: 'Joseph Flowers',     //    for your use case !
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @jail I'm trying to implement your solution but is jumping an error:  static defaultProps = { `> 4 |   static defaultProps = {
    |                       ^
  5 |           name: 'Default name...'
  6 |   };` node -- version ->       v6.3.1

Comment: @Jail, Why are you using React.PureComponent ?

Comment: Sorry @Jail Other question... How can I validate if props.name doesn't an empty string? cause the other componente is sending and empty string but in this cases I wanna set this by default value for example if this.props.name === '' ? '' this.props.name : 'Default value'

Comment: @JosephFlowers Can you give details about your error ? What's the message ? Can you copy/paste your code ?

Comment: @JosephFlowers Excellent question : PureComponent tells React that you are writing a pure component, which means a stateless component : what it renders only depends on the props it receives. Knowing that, React enables some performance optimizations.

Comment: @JosephFlowers First of all, the other component should not be sending an empty string if it want to rely on default value. 
In this case, you can still, in your render method, `return (!!this.props.name && this.props.name != '' ? this.props.name : 'Joseph Flowers');`

Answer (score 6):

You just have to pass props parameter in constructor method:

```
import React from 'react';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) { // <-- this parameter
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            name: props.name || 'Joseph Flowers' // <-- then used like this
        };
    }
}
```

Note that in some cases it's not an anti-pattern:

> (For more complex logic, simply isolate the computation in a method.)
>
> However, it's not an anti-pattern if you make it clear that the prop
>   is only seed data for the component's internally-controlled state:
>   Source: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html

BTW for ES6 if you want to set default properties you must to declare just next of the class declaration:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    /**
    This is the ES7 way to use
    static propTypes = {            
        name: React.PropTypes.string,
    }

    static defaultProps = {         
        name: 'My default value using ES7'
    }
    */

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        // this still could be the best solutions in cases
        // of the unexpected values in the props sent 
        // for the out side component
        this.state = {
            name: props.name && props.name !== '' ? props.name :'Joseph Flowers';
        };
    }
}

// This is the ES6 way to use
MyComponent.propTypes = {
    name: React.PropTypes.string
}

MyComponent.defaultProps = {
    name: 'My default value'
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent name="" />, document.getElementById('my-container-id'));
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, worked out pretty ok!!

Comment: Beware though ... if props.name change, it won't be reflected in your state ... This is anti-pattern unless you change your prop name to 'initialName', but it this case, you wouldn't need to hard code another one ...
More info : https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html

Comment: @Jalil thanks for the warning, for set 'const' components values could be a good solution

Comment: Did not get you ...What are you saying ?

Comment: You are right but if you just need set states with the props (For example a ajax REST url or whataver that will not change) once time, setting the states at constructor could be a good solution, don't you think?

Comment: Why would you put in component state some thing that will not change ... ? Just put in in props !

Answer (score 1):

You can do this for stateless components

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
 return <div>Hi {props.name || 'Joseph Flowers'}! </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In es7 you can init state like this.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    static propTypes = {
        title: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    }   

    // or pass from parent Componet 
    static defaultProps = {
        title: 'hello',
    }

    state = {
        title: this.props.title
    }
    // ...
}
```